# How to fix multiple click on button and (database quiz application)

Tags: java, android

I applied a question about firebase. There are buttons in the question and answer section. But when there is continuous clicks, the answers to the next questions are also clicked. How can I solve this?

this is QuestionActivity.java

```
@Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_question);

        question = findViewById(R.id.question);
        qCount = findViewById(R.id.question_num);
        timer = findViewById(R.id.coundown);

        option1 = findViewById(R.id.option1);
        option2 = findViewById(R.id.option2);
        option3 = findViewById(R.id.option3);
        option4 = findViewById(R.id.option4);

        option1.setOnClickListener(this);
        option2.setOnClickListener(this);
        option3.setOnClickListener(this);
        option4.setOnClickListener(this);
```

this is OnClick method

```
@Override
    public void onClick(View view) {
        int selectedOption = 0;


        switch (view.getId()) {
            case R.id.option1:
                selectedOption = 1;
                break;

            case R.id.option2:
                selectedOption = 2;
                break;

            case R.id.option3:
                selectedOption = 3;

                break;
            case R.id.option4:
                selectedOption = 4;

            default:

        }
        //  countdown.cancel();
        checkAnswer(selectedOption, view);


    }
```

and this is Question.java

```
public class Question {

    String question;
    String optionA;
    String optionB;
    String optionC;
    String optionD;
    int correctAns;


    public Question(String question, String optionA, String optionB, String optionC, String optionD, int correctAns) {
        this.question = question;
        this.optionA = optionA;
        this.optionB = optionB;
        this.optionC = optionC;
        this.optionD = optionD;
        this.correctAns = correctAns;
    }
```

Comment: `onClick` code please

Comment: Can you show which types have the gui elements you initialize in OnCreate ?

Comment: private TextView question, qCount, timer;
    private Button option1, option2, option3, option4;
    private int quesNum;
    private CountDownTimer countdown;
    private int score;
    private FirebaseFirestore firestore;
    private int setNo;
    private Dialog loadingDialog;
    private List<Question> questionList;

Answer (score 2):

You need add switch to your listener:

```
@Override
    public void onClick(View view) {
        switch (view.getId()) {
            case R.id.option1:
                    // click by first
                break;
            case R.id.option2:
                   // click by second
                break;
            case R.id.option3:

                break;
            case R.id.option4:

                break;
        }
    }
```

Comment: i m still have it. but when users click multiple, they can click to other questions. how i can fix it?

Comment: @WOTRONE you can set enabled for all buttons. Disable all button in start onClick() and enable in  last line in checkAnswer()

Comment: how i can do this? can you code and send ? i m not know how to fix it. thanks